# Semantic UI for React

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, styling, semantic-ui-react

I have an issue with styling React Components with semantic Ui for React (http://react.semantic-ui.com/). I know I can modify the Semantic UI's styles Core and I did that however sometime I want to put my own styles into their components.

And I really want to use BEM methodology CSS naming convention while defining class names.

Short example, I have `<Menu />` Component and I want to change a background of it, so I will add a class `<Menu className="menu-header">`, .menu-header class has different background-color property.

And the point is, that I cannot modify it without `!important`, because semantic UI has higher priority (they are grabbing elements more specific, with few classes not just by one like I want to). All styles are being caught by webpack, and my `.menu-header` styles are at the bottom of bundle.js - webpack output, lower than semantic UI's. The `.menu-header` class is being imported directly to my new component which uses `<Menu className="menu-header">` example by CSS loader in webpack.

What I can do in this case?

My ideas are that I can modify core of semantic ui, change everything out there, but it doesnt solve my problem. Whenever I will want to modify something again, I would have to use `!important` - I don't like it.

I realized that react inline js styling has the highest priority and it overrides semantic ui styles, but it is a little more complicated than less which I am using an I am not sure whether it would be a good approach in such a big app as the one I want to develop.

Answer (score 1):

I think the use of `!important` within semantic-ui should be labeled as a bug. I have ran into similar problems and the *easiest* way to solve it is using inline styles.

You can probably use something like [react css modules](https://github.com/gajus/react-css-modules) to help you with that task.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible. Someone would need to rewrite semantic ui in BEM.

I personally wouldn't use it unless it was in BEM/SASS, I'd assume there are quite a few others as well.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow - This answer is better suited as a comment, which with a little more reputation, you will be able to post. Until then try coming up with thorough answers that will add value to the community.